# Better way than setInterval to wait for an image load?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

This is really a simple affair, I just wonder if there is a better way to do it:

```
let el = document.querySelectorAll('#comic img');
let loadPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    let ticker = setInterval(() => {
        if (el[0].complete) {
            clearInterval(ticker);
            resolve();
        }
    }, 100);
    setTimeout(() => {
        clearInterval(ticker);
        reject('Timeout');
    }, 5000)
});

loadPromise.then(() => {
    console.log(el[0].naturalWidth);
    let container = document.querySelectorAll('.main-wrapper > div > section > section.column.column-1.grid-left-4.grid-width-16');
    container[0].style.width = (el[0].naturalWidth + 420) + 'px';
});
```

I must wait for the image to load, so I know its size so that I can adjust an element on the page.

But `setInterval`(aka polling the element) seems so... medieval. Is there a nicer way in modern JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Must wait for the image to load" ... "Is there a nicer way?"

Yes, 
At first, instead of accessing the image by index `el[0]` - extract the image at once and give the variable meaningful name:

```
let img = document.querySelectorAll('#comic img')[0];
```

Next, you need to embed **`"load"`** event listener into Promise *executor function* to ensure the image has loaded:

```
let loadPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    img.addEventListener('load', function() {
       resolve();
    });
    setTimeout(() => {
        if (!img.complete) reject('Timeout');
    }, 5000)
});
loadPromise.then(() => {
    console.log(img.naturalWidth);
    let container = document.querySelectorAll('.main-wrapper > div > section > section.column.column-1.grid-left-4.grid-width-16');
    container[0].style.width = (img.naturalWidth + 420) + 'px';
});
```

Comment: This answer is very poor -1. `Image.complete` property indicates the status of the loading process not the whether or not the image has actually loaded. As the image is queried from the page it may have already loaded in which case nether the load or timeouts will resolve the promise.

Comment: @Blindman67, such a comment does not consider situations when `img` element was added to the document, but its `src` attribute is set or changed/delayed in another event/function

Comment: Even if you set the `src` the image can fail to load and the load event will not fire while the timeout will not detect that there was an error as `complete` will be true

Comment: Ugh. Must have been really tired to not think of looking into events. The `.complete` attribute criticism is valid, though I'm not certain it is trivial to fix the promise. Arguably however it can be simplified further by not promisifying the callback, which conveniently also avoids the `.complete` issue.